# Excel Pivot Table Row labels

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I made a pivot table in Excel with three categories in the Rows box. I then copy-pasted the table into a new document. I want to have each row include the variables which I used in to create the pivot table. For example, here is what my data looks like:

`Row Labels    Bear    Deer
    Before
      C01
        1          1       3
        2          0       1
        3          1       0
        4          0       5
        5          0       7
      C02
        1          0       0
        2          0       0
        3          0       1
        4          1       2
        5          0       5
    After
      C01
        1          1       5
        2          0       0
        3          0       1
        4          0       5
        5          1       2
      C02
        1          1       9
        2          0       2
        3          1       1
        4          0       0
        5          0       0`

And I want it to look like this:

`Phase  Point     Day       Bear    Deer
Before C01        1          1       3
Before C01        2          0       1
Before C01        3          1       0
Before C01        4          0       5
Before C01        5          0       7
Before C02        1          0       0
Before C02        2          0       0
Before C02        3          0       1
Before C02        4          1       2
Before C02        5          0       5
After  C01        1          1       5
After  C01        2          0       0
After  C01        3          0       1
After  C01        4          0       5
After  C01        5          1       2
After  C02        1          1       9
After  C02        2          0       2
After  C02        3          1       1
After  C02        4          0       0
After  C02        5          0       0`

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the pivot, go to PivotTable Options, Display Tab.
Click on "Classic Pivot Table Layout"

Go to each field (column), right click, field settings, layout & print tab.
Click on "Repeat Item Labels"

That should give you the table you're looking for.